# Con qué, a qué, lo que

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Las siquientes frases equivalen a "Do you still remember what you've committed at first? "

> 1. ¿Todavía recuerdas **con qué** te comprometiste al principio?
> 2. ¿Todavía recuerdas **a qué** te comprometiste al principio?
> 3. ¿Todavía recuerdas **lo que** te comprometiste al principio?

¿Son todas correctas estas frases? ¿Si no, por qué?

In a dictionary, it is written "(dar su palabra) comprometerse a + infinitve" = "to promise to + infinitive". What is the "infinitive" for the second sentence above "¿Todavía recuerdas *a que* te comprometiste al principio?". Is "que" an implied infinitivo?

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
For "me he comprometido *para* salir esta noche", if I change "para" to "a", is it the same meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La forma correcta de utilizar el verbo comprometer es con la preposición "a" seguido por el verbo en infinitivo. La preposición "con" en este caso sirve para indicar con quien fue el compromiso.

Por ejemplo:

> Me comprometí con la empresa a venir todos los domingos hasta que se termine el proyecto.

De esta oración se podrían hacer las siguientes preguntas:

> ¿Con quién te comprometiste?
>
> Con la empresa.
>
> ¿A qué te comprometiste?
>
> A venir todos los domingos hasta que se termine el proyecto.

Por lo tanto la primera y la tercera oración son incorrectas.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**

La tercera oración sería correcta de este modo:

> ¿Todavía recuerdas a **lo que** te comprometiste al principio?

Notese que "que" no está acentuada. Si no estuviera acompañada por el lo entonces sería:

> ¿Todavía recuerdas **a qué** te comprometiste al principio?

Respondiendo a tu pregunta de que cuál es el infinitivo de la segunda oración, en este caso como es una pregunta "**qué**" es el que está reemplazando al infinitivo.

El uso de "**para**" es correcto para indicar el proposito del compromiso, es decir qué se busca obtener realizando dicha acción, por ejemplo:

> Me he comprometido con mi mamá a sacar la basura de la casa **para** que me deje salir esta noche.

Comment: Thank you! 1) For the first sentence, must we use "con quien" (with whom) and not "con que"? (with what) 2) How about "me he comprometido para salir esta noche"? It does not use "a".

Comment: @Cadenza: 1) Yes, since you can't take a commitment with an inanimate object. 2) That one is a different construct and a slightly different meaning. It is valid.