# Qué vs Lo Que in Noun Clause That Is a Direct Object

Tags: pronombres, pronombre-interrogativo

Are *qué* and *lo que* interchangeable in this context, where they introduce a noun clause that is a direct object?

```
¡Mira lo que me dijo que no puedo hablar inglés!
¡Mira qué me dijo que no puedo hablar inglés!

Dime lo que te pasa.
Dime qué te pasa.

Hice lo que tuve que hacer.
Hice qué tuve que hacer.
```

Obviously one would not say "Qué más me ha gustado es...," where that clause is the subject, but it is possible to say "Dime qué te pasó," where "qué te pasó" is now an object. Are "lo que" and "qué" interchangeable when the noun clause is the object?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning and use of ‘lo que’](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/39848/meaning-and-use-of-lo-que)

Comment: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2588/19361

Comment: Typing "lo que" in the top search bar displays many related Q&A with the topic

Comment: No, I understand the grammatical uses of "lo que," "que," and "qué," but this is a very specific gray area that I have not been able to find a lot of information on. I have asked my native-speaker family members, and even they were conflicted on some. https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/tell%20me%20what%20happened For example, this sentence is translated both ways, with both the interrogative "qué" and the neuter pronoun "lo que."

Comment: Obviously one would not say "Qué más me ha gustado es...," where that clause is the subject, but it is possible to say "Dime qué te pasó," where "qué te pasó" is now an object. Are "lo que" and "qué" interchangeable when the noun clause is the object?

Comment: In "Dime qué te pasó", "qué" is the subject of "pasó". "qué te pasó" as a whole is the object of "dime". You can also find "qué" introducing the subject: Qué sabe él y qué no sabe es una incógnita.

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta corta es no, tienen funciones distintas.

---

Creo que la razón principal de tu confusión estriba en los signos, que no están colocados o no están siendo utilizados de forma apropiada.

"Dime qué te pasó", aunque se entiende, es mejor escribirla de de forma que no existan confusiones principalmente para aquellos que están aprendiendo español. **Dime, "¿ qué te pasó?"**.

Cuando se observa un "**qué**" acentuado (acento ortográfico o tilde) hay que pensar siempre como regla general que se trata de una frase con sentido interrogativo o exclamativo y por tanto, la entonación debe de ser la habitual ante una oración interrogativa o exclamativa, aunque a veces existen excepciones como en ¡Que te calles!, donde el "que" no lleva tilde.

Para personas que están estudiando español seria conveniente, como introducción, que estas oraciones fueran entre interrogaciones o exclamaciones, dejando para más tarde el estudio de las interrogativas y exclamativas indirectas, aunque en muchas ocasiones, más de las que debieran, los signos de puntuación por alguna razón ya sea por desconocimiento, despiste, costumbre... son omitidos, mal colocados o utilizados de manera deficiente, ya que por regla general se sobrentienden, aunque estos no se encuentren. Todo esto puede resultar confuso para quien no este habituado, pues como digo, no se suele hacer un buen uso de signos como acentos (tildes), comas, interrogaciones, exclamaciones...

- **¡Mira! Lo que me dijo es que no puedo hablar inglés.** Afirmando una orden de lo que alguien le dijo ante otra persona.
- **¡Mira lo que me dijo, que no puedo hablar inglés!** Afirmando de manera incrédula o en forma de queja ante otra persona. (Mira que decirme esas cosas a mi) ("**lo**" como pronombre en esta parte de la oración sustituye aquello que te dijo, *que no puedo hablar inglés*).
- **¡Mira!, ¿ qué me dijo?, que no puedo hablar inglés.** Preguntando y auto-respondiendo lo que le dijo, ante otra persona. (para después extender la información ...que no se enteraba de lo que decía ....)
- **Hice lo que tuve que hacer**. (Hice aquello que tuve que hacer) ("lo y aquello" como pronombre sustituye aquel proceder o comportamiento que el sujeto realizó).
- **Hice qué tuve que hacer**. (La oración esta mal construida, o no tiene sentido en este contexto). A no ser que uno mismo se pregunte. ¿Hice...?, ¿ Qué tuve que hacer?.

**Rizando el rizo**

Para ampliar conocimiento, por si sigues observando otras aparentes incongruencias, te recomiendo leer el  **"ser focalizador o es enfático"** que se da en algunas partes de América y que si no estas prevenido puede confundirte.

Ejemplos;

- «**yo vivo es en Bogotá**» - «Donde yo vivo es en Bogotá»
- «**ellos quieren es poder**» - «Lo que ellos quieren es poder»
- «**yo quería era plata**» -  «Lo que yo quería era plata»

[¿Cuál es el análisis gramatical del verbo "ser" en el sentido "en realidad"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/41061/cu%c3%a1l-es-el-an%c3%a1lisis-gramatical-del-verbo-ser-en-el-sentido-en-realidad/41064#41064)

**PD.**

RAE

**Qué** - qué Del lat. quid.

https://dle.rae.es/qu%C3%A9#UkdF1CE

RAE

**Que** que Del lat. quid. - **que - el que, la que, lo que - lo que.**

https://dle.rae.es/que

---

Comment: La oración "Dime qué te pasó" es perfectamente correcta y no tiene ningún problema de construcción.

Comment: Hey Gustavson, but why would que carry a tilde here?

Comment: @user13229973 Because it is an interrogative pronoun. I will write a reply shortly.

Comment: I think you mean an accent. Tilde is ~

Comment: @SebastianPojman-Malo In Spanish, we call the written accent either "tilde" or "acento ortográfico". And reserve the term "acento prosódico" to refer to an oral, unwritten accent. Ther term "acento" is therefore ambiguous.

Comment: Hola Gustavson, llevas razón, pero esa es la misma razón por la que Sebastián esta confundido y ha realizado esta pregunta. Era una manera, en mi opinión, de que pudiera comprender este tipo de oraciones un poco mejor y a partir de ahí, reconocer las oraciones interrogativas, aunque estás no lleven en algunos casos el signo que representa de forma escrita la entonación interrogativa. Gracias a tus comentarios he remodelado la cuestión. A veces damos por sabidas, yo el primero, cosas que no lo son tanto para otras personas. Si deseas que cambie o añada algo, házmelo saber. Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: En oraciones escritas, es difícil para un foráneo percibir las entonaciones y como actuar ante los distintos signos dobles de entonación u otros signos diacríticos  si no esta habituado, o alguien te explica aspectos que nosotros sobrentendemos y damos por sabido. Gracias de nuevo por tus comentarios.

Comment: "Mira qué me dijo". El predicado subordinado "qué me dijo" no puede desligarse del verbo "Mira" porque significa "darse cuenta", distinto es el caso que dijera: ¡Mira qué caliente baila! En ese caso, podría omitirse "Mira" y decir solo ¡Qué caliente baila! sin que varíe su significado porque de hecho con solo esa exclamación está indicando que lo hace: El bailar caliente.

Answer (score 2):

There are three "que" in Spanish:

1. Interrogative or exclamatory "qué". This is always stressed, whether the question or exclamation is direct or indirect:

- ¿**Qué** pasa? (direct question) / Dime **qué** pasa. (indirect question) (Tell me **what** happens.)
- ¡**Qué** buena es la película! (direct exclamation) / No puedo creer **qué** buena es la película. (indirect exclamation)

Although sentences like "No puedo creer lo buena que es la película" may be heard more often, the indirect exclamation above is perfectly correct and definitely more frequent than the equally correct:

- No puedo creer cuán buena es la película.

In this [tweet](https://twitter.com/raeinforma/status/1329384699047923713) from RAE, we can find a similar example. In fact:

- Mira qué guapa va.

is equivalent to:

- Mira lo guapa que va.

just as:

- No puedo creer qué buena es la película.

is equivalent to:

- No puedo creer lo buena que es la película.

To further support my point that "qué" with adverbial value (that is, before adjectives or adverbs) can introduce indirect exclamations we can read the following in [this PhD thesis](https://gredos.usal.es/bitstream/handle/10366/135810/DEL_FurutaY_VerbosDelEspa%F1ol.pdf;jsessionid=1F33984668C8812491BBA6E7CB623025?sequence=1) by a student from Universidad de Salamanca (page 46):

> - El exclamativo *qué* puede tener funcionamiento adverbial, es decir, puede modificar un adverbio o un adjetivo, pero el interrogativo, no:
>
> (65) ¿Han visto qué mal queda todo ello? (La vanguardia, 22/03/1994, CREA) /
> *Le pregunté qué mal quedaba todo ello.
>
> (66) Pero te has fijado qué curiosa es la naturaleza (…) (Sánchez-Ostiz, M., Un infierno en el jardín, CREA)

"Le pregunté qué mal quedaba todo ello" is correctly marked as incorrect because the verb in the interrogative to be turned into indirect speech is "han visto": Les pregunté si habían visto qué mal quedaba todo ello.

As an alternative to sentences (65) and (66) above, we can also say:

65a. ¿Han visto lo mal que queda todo ello?

66a. Pero te has fijado lo curiosa que es la naturaleza.

However, just as I claimed, sentences (65) and (66) are perfectly correct.

In ["Enciclopedia de Lingüística Hispánica"](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=GkF-CwAAQBAJ&pg=PA765&lpg=PA765&dq=%22no%20puedo%20creer%22%20exclamativa&source=bl&ots=tZhTWe3p9i&sig=ACfU3U3zSb9hK_SGl4NrkT_MOaRs4-7-yw&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwia2NCG2vz6AhUXkZUCHUTHBqo4UBDoAXoECBUQAw#v=onepage&q=%22no%20puedo%20creer%22%20exclamativa&f=false), we can read:

> (11) Exclamativas indirectas:
>
> a. Tú sabes/Ya verás cómo lavan los vasos en este restaurante.
>
> b. No puedo creer qué vida lleva.
>
> c. Me parece mentira cuánto puede comer este perro.
>
> Además, las exclamativas indirectas no pueden introducirse con *si*, porque son siempre parciales, y no admiten ni el subjuntivo ni el infinitivo, sino solo el indicativo.

Example (b) above clearly shows that, contrary to what other users claim, "no puedo creer" can be followed by an indirect exclamatory clause in the indicative mood. The subjunctive will only be used when "no puedo creer" introduces a statement rather than an exclamation, as in: "No puedo creer que lleve una vida tan infeliz".

Once again, (b) can be paraphrased as:

b.1. No puedo creer la vida que lleva.

2. Relative pronoun (always unstressed):

- La película **que** vi es muy buena.

3. Conjunction (always unstressed):

- Me dijo **que** no pasa nada. (He told me (**that**) nothing happens.)

(Notice that, while in (1) the English word for "qué" is "what", in (3) the English word for "que" is "that".)

Now, "lo que" can always be replaced with stressed "qué" (an interrogative or exclamatory pronoun) **when the verb preceding "lo que" is a verb of speaking or thinking**. Only verbs of speech and mental process are capable of being followed by indirect questions and exclamations:

As written, the first pair of sentences is not well constructed because the first "lo que" should be merely "que" (conjunction):

```
¡Mira que me dijo que no puedo hablar inglés! (Notice THAT he told me I can't speak in English)

Dime lo que te pasa. (CORRECT)
Dime qué te pasa. (CORRECT)

Hice lo que tuve que hacer. (CORRECT)
Hice qué tuve que hacer. (WRONG because "hacer" is not a verb of speaking or thinking.)
```

To be correct, the punctuation of the first pair of sentences should be revised as follows:

```
¡Mira lo que me dijo: que no puedo hablar inglés! (Look at what she told me -- that I can't speak English!)
¡Mira qué me dijo: que no puedo hablar inglés!
```

Comment: Hey @Gustavson, this is very helpful - when you say verb of thinking you mean such as pensar, opinar, creer, suponer and etc., yes?

Comment: Exactly. Also: imaginar, deducir, prever...

Comment: One question while I'm reading this: Couldn't the first one be interpreted as "Look at what she told me that I can't speak English!"? I say that because "mirar que..." usually means "remember that..." or "make sure...," where as "mirar [object]" means "look at [object]." That seems more appropriate here.

Comment: On reading your comment, I realized that the sentence could be interpreted as you said if there were a punctuation mark in the middle. I've added it in my reply. Thank you.

Comment: @Gustavson ¿Estás seguro que "No puedo creer QUÉ buena es la película (indirect exclamation)" es correcta? Yo siempre diría: "No puedo creer LO buena que es la película'" o ""No puedo creer QUE sea TAN buena"

Comment: @cocteau Sí, la oración: "No puedo creer qué buena es la película" es tan correcta como las otras versiones que propusiste. Si tienes dudas, puedo buscar ejemplos similares en libros de Internet.

Comment: “No puedo creer lo buena que es la película” is the only way I’ve ever heard it

Comment: It may be more usual, but both are equally correct.

Comment: @Gustavson Respetuosamente, me parece una frase mal construida.

Comment: @cocteau El hecho de que no la uses no significa que sea incorrecta. Estoy muy seguro de lo que digo pero, ya que no me crees, buscaré documentación que me avale. Próximamente, la verás incluida en mi respuesta.

Comment: @Gustavason No es que yo lo diga, lo dicen lingüistas españoles, latinoamericanos y de centroamericana, es simplemente incongruente y no tiene que ver con el registro o el uso.

Comment: @cocteau No sé a qué lingüistas te refieres. Si lees lo que agregué, verás que tanto la RAE como otros estudiosos me dan la razón.

Answer (score -1):

> Cuando las **cláusulas nominales** se utilizan en lugar de un **objeto directo**, sustituyen "**algo**" en una oración.

Por lo tanto en la frase:

- No puedo creer [lo buena que es la película] cabe la pregunta:
- ¿Qué no puedes creer?
  R. Lo buena que es la película <=> algo <=> eso <=> **objeto directo** <=> **cláusula nominal**.

En la frase:

- Mira(verbo de percepción)+[lo guapa que va] OD=CN
- Mira **[eso]**.

La construcción "lo guapa que va" posee una valor exclamativo, tal como lo sería si se dijera en forma directa:

- Mira qué guapa va.

En este caso sí serían trasladable al predicado subordinado, pero no es así para todos los contextos, este es un caso puntual(verbos de percepción)

Generalmente las frases que comienzan con una negación tal como "**No puedo creer**" necesitan el uso del subjuntivo

> Encontramos el **subjuntivo** en cláusulas nominales en dos contextos:

> 1. El contenido de la cláusula subordinada no puede afirmarse como real, ya que se trata de algo deseado, sugerido, **dudado** o **negado**.

Por lo tanto debe decir algo como:

- No puedo creer que [**sea(subjuntivo presente     Tercera persona del singular)**] tan buena.

> Una **cláusula nominal siempre es una cláusula dependiente**, lo que significa que **es una parte de la oración que NO puede sostenerse por sí misma** como una idea independiente.

> Por ejemplo, en la frase "No sé dónde es el concierto" La segunda parte, "dónde es el concierto" **está inconclusa**, necesita de la primera parte "No sé" para que tenga sentido.

> Por lo tanto si haces la pregunta "¿Sabes dónde es el concierto?, verás que **"dónde" indica el inicio de la cláusula nominal**.

Por lo tanto en la frase:

- No puedo creer [**lo buena que es** la película]
  "lo buena que es" necesita de "No puedo creer" para que tenga sentido, de lo contrario quedaría igualmente inconclusa.

Del mismo modo que si usamos "que" como nexo de la subordinada en función del complemento directo:

- [No] puedo creer {que [sea] tan buena}
  Si hacemos la pregunta:
- ¿Puedes creer**LO**?(=El que **LO** sea)
- ¿Puedes creer **que LO sea**?
  ("que" indica el comienzo de la cláusula nominal)

Sin embargo en:

- No puedo creer+qué buena es la película

Me resulta absolutamente ilógico entender "qué buena es la película" como una cláusula nominal porque se sostiene por sí misma y porque como exclamativa indirecta ahí sería incongruente, lo cual es totalmente diferente a cuando se da el caso de ser precedida por verbos de percepción tales como "mirar" y "fijarse" donde el sentido es "Darse cuenta de algo".

Mira qué me dijo". El predicado subordinado "qué me dijo" no puede desligarse del verbo "Mira" porque significa "darse cuenta", distinto es el caso que dijera: ¡Mira qué caliente baila! En ese caso, podría omitirse "Mira" y decir solo ¡Qué caliente baila! sin que varíe su significado porque de hecho con solo esa exclamación está indicando que lo hace: El bailar caliente. –

> a. **Mira** qué coche se ha comprado.
> b. **Verás** qué tonterías dice.

> Ambos verbos, mirar y fijarse, pertenecen a la categoría de **verbos de percepción visual**, los cuales son proclives a que su significado léxico se difumine abandonando su estatus como verbo y dando paso a un valor de tipo gramatical. Este hecho lo vemos más claro si modificamos el **predicado subordinado**. Si nos fijamos en los ejemplos que siguen, no es necesario que haya un **referente visual** para emplear este enunciado, más bien de su significado se desprende el valor de prestar atención.
> (64) a. **Mira** qué cosas dice.
> b. **Fíjate** qué tonterías llega a decir.
> Te recomiendo:
> [APROXIMACIÓN SINTÁCTICA A LAS ORACIONES EXCLAMATIVAS DEL ESPAÑOL Irene Tirado](https://septentrio.uit.no/index.php/borealis/article/download/3877/3717/14275)

> Las oraciones dc (21) pueden tener dos sentidos **si prescindimos de la entonación**. En tal caso las oraciones subordinadas pueden interpretarse o bien como interrogativas indirectas o bien como **exclamativas indirectas**. En el primer caso, se prescinde del juicio de valor que va ligado a la lectura exclamativa. (21 ti) significaría «Mira a ver quién está ahí» y (21 c) **podría interpretarse en un sentido neutro muy diferente del que posee si se trata de una exclamativa indirecta** (= «vivía muy bien o muy mal»). Nos interesa resaltar que para explicar esta doble lectura no es necesario interpretar una elipsis de «a ver» en (21 ti) ni de «de bien» o «de mal» en (21 c), sino tan sólo aplicar la citada división entre las interrogativas dependientes y las exclamativas dependientes.

Te recomiendo que leas [Sobre la interrogación indirecta
de Ignacio Bosque](https://revistas.ucm.es/index.php/DICE/article/download/DICE8282110013A/13511/0) donde se profundiza las complejidades de la exclamativas indirectas.

> De todas las estructuras subordinadas que estamos estudiando no cabe duda de que la que presenta una sintaxis más compleja es **Lo fuerte que es**. Existe una abundante bibliografía sobre la gramática de esta construcción que no podremos analizar aquí. En este trabajo nos interesa resaltar tan sólo que tal oración nominalizada actúa como interrogativa y como exclamativa indirecta. **No podemos detenemos, por tanto, en las secuencias en las que lo fuerte que es equivale a que sea tan fuerte o a que es muy fuerte”, sino únicamente y de manera muy breve, en las que equivale a cómo es de fuerte**.

Por último decir que comparar "lo que" con "qué" en todos los posibles casos sería en vano porque es demasiado amplio, sólo un ejemplo coloquial:

- Para **qué** llamas po(=Por fin te dignaste a llamar ingrato, no lo habías hecho, y ahora lo estás haciendo)
- (Mira) para/por **lo que** llamas po(ya se enteró de la causa su llamada y la considera absurda)

https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/tell%20me%20what%20happened

En enlace que pusiste cada una de esas oraciones varía en tono, registro, acentuación y región.

> Dime qué pasó, Tommy. - Tropecé y me despellejé la rodilla.

Este tipo de construcciones generalmente las veo en traducciones del inglés, en autores hispanos que nacieron en un país donde se habla el inglés o que escriben en inglés y el editor los traduce a un español medio Spanglish característico de su Región o derechamente me suena a doblaje. En ese ejemplo diría algo como "Dime lo que te pasó" y si digo "dime qué pasó" es para que me cuente el accidente en general, esperaría que me contestara: ¿Qué pasó con qué? Y por lo tanto le diría algo como: Con tu rodilla ¿Cómo fue el accidente?

---

Agradecería que junto a los votos negativos dieran su **argumento** o **el porqué**. Gracias :D