# Usar ¡Mira! en discutir un ruido

Tags: vocabulario

En [una otra pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/41244/qu%c3%a9-vs-lo-que-in-noun-clause-that-is-a-direct-object), se presentó la siguiente frase:

> ¡Mira lo que me dijo que no puedo hablar inglés!

¿Es de verdad aceptable usar «¡Mira!» de pedir atención en español si el objetivo es un ruido, lo que no se puede ver? Como hablador de inglés, me parace extraño decir «*Look what he told me*». Supongo que sería diferente si refiera a una carta u otro escrito, pero en general, ¿se prefiere la siguiente?

> ¡Escucha lo que me dijo que no puedo hablar inglés!

A mí me parece mejor decir «*Listen to*» en inglés o «¡Escucha!» en español porque aún no se puede ver lo que se ha dicho, sí se puede oírlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mirar no solo significa *ver*, también tiene otras acepciones:

> 2. tr. Observar las acciones de alguien.
>    4. tr. Tener en cuenta, atender.

https://dle.rae.es/mirar?m=form

En este caso, mirar se utiliza como *check this out* o *check it out*

---

De todos modos, hay que tener en cuenta que la frase está mal redactada, lo correcto es:

> ¡Mira lo que me dijo! Que no puedo hablar inglés.

Es necesaria la pausa entre la llamada de atención y la respuesta.

Comment: I have in my mind the Italian "guarda", they use it for everything and it doesn't mean just to see: 
*guarda cosa mi ha detto*

Answer (score 0):

¿Es de verdad aceptable usar «¡**Mira**!» para pedir atención en español, si el objetivo es un ruido, lo que no se puede ver?

---

Si, es aceptable y de uso muy habitual. Como muy bien ha precisado, "mirar", **¡Mira!**, en este caso es entre otras cosas, advertir, atender, obedecer, examinar, pedir, solicitar atención u observar algo. Normalmente cuando se dice **¡Mira!**, se entiende que algo es urgente y la persona que habla o va hablar sobre algún tema, reclama el interés del que escucha para algo que ha pasado o esta pasando. Esta "urgencia", por **antonomasia**, se extiende igualmente a aquello que se va a "decir" en el sentido, "***Pon atención a las cosas que te voy a contar, ya que son importantes***", por tanto y en este sentido "**Mirar**" también se entiende como "**Escuchar**" ¡Escucha lo que me dijo, que no puedo hablar inglés!.

Por otro lado, también existe un punto de confluencia entre "**Mirar y Escuchar**", mientras que "**mirar**", las imágenes las vemos presentes allá donde nos indican, en "**escuchar**" las imágenes de aquello que nos cuentan u oímos las elaboramos en nuestro propio cerebro, un ruido de un taladro, una explosión, un niño llorar... de esta manera, cuando alguien nos va a contar una noticia o historia de alguna forma también le estamos dando vida en nuestra mente, por ello muchas veces decimos "**No me cuentes películas**", en el sentido, "No me cuentes historias, problemas o lo que alguien dijo...", pues contar algo es, siempre en cierto modo, "*ver una película*".

En cualquier caso, en ambos casos, cuando nos interpelan con este tipo de interjecciones, "**Mirar o Escuchar**", la atención captada de forma solicita por parte del que se expresa, debe de estar presente de manera especial.

**Antonomasia** - *Figura retórica de pensamiento que consiste bien en sustituir un nombre apelativo por el de la cualidad que le caracteriza o que se le atribuye, bien en sentido inverso*.